# How to make Flot Graph workable with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, flot

I have two external arrays for x and y axis and I am trying do make a simple graph with them. What am I doing wrong here?

```
<div id="graph"></div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var array = [1300, 1400, 1500, 1600, 1700];
        var array1  = [1, 3, 5, 6];
        var d1 = [array1, array];  
        $.plot("#graph", [ d1 ]);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign some styles to your graph div since it will contain a canvas element.
If you check the console you should have a js error similar to:

> Uncaught Error: Invalid dimensions for plot, width = 1350, height = 0

Assigning a value for the height to your div should fix the problem

```
  <div id="graph" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i have css style tag in my html. It still doesn't work.

Comment: do you get any other error in your javascript console ? can you replicate the same problem on jsfiddle or similar apps ?

Comment: i have errors in the console and it doesn't work in jsfiddle too.   https://jsfiddle.net/0n2r9vnw/

Comment: maybe you should add those errors to your question. Can you post the link to jsfiddle ?

Comment: oops, sorry, i wanted to say that i have no errors in the console. everything seems normal there there  . This is a link to jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0n2r9vnw/

Comment: you also need to add the external resource to jquery.flot.js, also pay attention to the structure of the data: https://jsfiddle.net/0n2r9vnw/3/

Answer (score 0):

The right dataformat for flot is different from what you are trying. You need an array of datapoints where each datapoint is an array of at least two values (these being the x and y values). For your data this would look like this:

```
var d1 = [[1, 1300], [3, 1400], [5, 1500], ...];  
$.plot("#graph", [ d1 ]);
```

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0n2r9vnw/4/) here. And see the [documentation](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#data-format) for more info.